# Split folder having files into 50 MB subfolders using bat or powershell

Tags: batch, powershell, script, batch-file, bash-scripting

I have a 700 MB folder containing 24k text files with varying sizes. I want to create new folders each having ~50 MB size so that I can process them in excel using vba as it has row limit of 10 lakh lines.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Showing us what you've tried will be appreciated

Comment: Post your code and point out where you're stuck and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: I could split files according to certain files in each folder (that doesn't serve my purpose) but I could not get any related code when searched then I posted it here.

Comment: You can use `dir /b` to get a list of all the files, which you can then step through, moving files and counting as you go, and after every 50 moves increment the target directory. That should give you the guidelines for a solution, but don't expect someone to write it for you: we don't do that on this site.

Comment: How are you correlating 50 Megabytes equals the number of rows you need?  The row limit for modern versions of excel is 1,048,576.

Comment: When I imported around 4000 files having size 51 MB, there was data of 1,017,000 rows. So that was just my guess.

Comment: Create a file hit enter 10 times and save it. Create another which has millions of digits of PI without a line break. The result would be a single line versus multiple with the size of files not correlating to the number of lines. Using `Get-ChildItem` would allow you to get size and name of files in PowerShell.

Comment: @Seth You're right, but files and data being in same format I guessed so.

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad I posted as answer the script I used so far to get this done. Please check and mark as answer if it fits your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interrested into doing this as well, so here is the PowerShell code I use.  This will get all files of your main folder, and move them into 10MB subfolders. Feel free to adapt values and names to your need.

```
# Replace with your base folder's path
$baseFolder = "C:\Users\you\myHugeFolder"

# Replace with the desired value for the subfolders to create
$maxSubFolderSize = 10MB

# Get all files contained in your base folder (could use the -recurse switch if needed)
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem $baseFolder

# Setting the subfolders naming convention : a name and a suffix
$baseSubFolder = "SubFolder-"
[int]$index = 0

# Creating the first subfolder
$subFolder = "SubFolder-" + "$index"
New-Item -Path $subFolder -Type Directory -Force

# Now processing the files
foreach ($file in $allFiles)
{
    # Evaluating the size of the current subfolder
    $subFolderSize = ((Get-ChildItem $subFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)

    # If the current subfolder size is greater than the limit, create a new subfolder and begin to copy files in it
    if([int]$subFolderSize -gt [int]$maxSubFolderSize/1MB)
    {
        $index++
        $subFolder = $baseSubFolder + $index
        New-Item -Path $subFolder -Type Directory -Force
        Write-Verbose -Message "Created folder $subFolder"
        Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $subFolder
    }
    # If the current subfolder is not yet greater that the limit, continue copying files in it
    else {
        Move-Item $file.FullName -Destination $subFolder
    }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Ran script for 1MB, but all folder size are having size >1.5 MB. Script has created 23 folders. I think that will be fine. Just one question, is it possible to create folders each having files such that count of lines =10 lakh.

Comment: Then you can adapt the size in the variable to match your need. There might be differences between size on disk and actual size.

Comment: OK. Thanks, anyway this will be helpful for me to go ahead!